# WPF Combobox binding Question

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have a 2 Table.

**Product**
 ProductName
 CategoryID

**Category**
ID
CategoryName

I'm filling combobox to table named 'category'.

**Code**

```
Product currentProduct=datacontext.products.FirstOrDefault();
this.datacontext=currentProduct;
combobox1.Itemssource=datacontext.categories;
```

**XAML**

```
<Textbox Text="{Binding Path=ProductName}"></Textbox>
<Combobox x:Name="combobox1" SelectedItem="Binding Path=CategoryID"></Combobox>
```

When click save button, I'm doing `datacontext.SubmitChanges()`

ProductName changed. But CategoryID not changed.

My target is when i select from combobox, selected category ID  set to CategoryID of currentProduct. `(like currentProduct.CategoryID=(Category as combobox1.SelectedItem).ID)`

How to do is from xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the `SelectedValue` property of the `ComboBox` to the `CategoryID` of the product, not the SelectedItem. You also need to set the `SelectedValuePath` property :

```
<Combobox x:Name="combobox1" SelectedValuePath=CategoryID, SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CategoryID, Mode=TwoWay}"></Combobox>
```